# Website going down when new ec2 is added via autoscaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We use elastic beanstalk for auto scaling EC2. Whenever a new instance is added automatically, website goes down for a couple of minutes. Can someone please help in resolving the same. Is there something wrong in Launch configuration/auto scaling config?

Answer (score 1):

Preferably we'd like more information to be able to properly answer your question. But going on only this, my guess is that the health-check for your loadbalancer says the instance is healthy before it is actually up. 
That way, since it is a new instance which is not utilized yet, new traffic will get directed to that host first, without it being ready.

Does your loadbalancer generate logs that you can see in cloudwatch? If so, what do they say?

Answer (score 0):

Please read on `ELB Connection Draining`, I guess this is your issue.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elb-connection-draining-remove-instances-from-service-with-care/